# I think there is a bug with the duck thingy

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I think there is a bug with the duck thingy, when I click on it, then click on 'no' the popup still pops up telling me its listening. Is this a bug, or is it on purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature!

See [a duplicate question on the network-wide meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308581/213556)

Short version is: It's not *really* listening. It's just an animation.

Answer (score 2):

Some may consider it a feature, but I kinda thought it was a bug.

If you want the duck gone. I mean really gone, not just until you refresh the page. There are instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308582/347908).

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature. The duck does not require a microphone to function.
It works perfectly well with or without it.
Do give it a try!
The choice is offered to give the illusion of control.